# How to write a Select Case condition for an interval of integers?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to read the values of every row in an Excel sheet in a certain column and set a text in another column depending on the numeric value.

I'm facing an overflow error using `CInt` function. I want to be certain the value I get is used as an Integer. The greatest value I have in that column is *43803* so Integer should be enough. However, I read I need to use Long for referring to columns/rows in code, so I changed `CInt` to `CLng`. Now the overflow error is gone but *ALL* rows are considered *Category B*.

My lowest numeric value in the column is *329*.

```
Sub insertColumnCategory()
    Dim cellValue As Long
    Dim lastColumn As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    lastColumn = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count + 1

    Columns(lastColumn).Insert
    ActiveSheet.Columns(lastColumn).NumberFormat = "General"

    With ActiveSheet
       lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    For i = 2 To lastRow
        cellValue = CLng(Cells(i, 21).Value)

        Select Case cellValue
        Case Is <= 0
            Cells(i, 22).Value = "Category A"
        Case Is >= 1, Is <= 30
            Cells(i, 22).Value = "Category B"
        Case Is >= 31, Is <= 60
            Cells(i, 22).Value = "Category C"
        Case Is >= 61, Is <= 90
            Cells(i, 22).Value = "Category D"
        Case Is >= 91, Is <= 180
            Cells(i, 22).Value = "Category E"
        Case Is >= 181, Is <= 365
            Cells(i, 22).Value = "Category F"
        Case Is > 365
            Cells(i, 22).Value = "Category G"
        End Select
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Int limit in VBA is about 32,000

Comment: `Case Is >= 1, Is <= 30` could be `Case 1 To 30`

Comment: Intergers are signed in `VBA` so the range is much lower than you suspect: `-32768` to `+32768`

Comment: ^ Technically the upper limit is `32767`. OP - worth giving [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/data-type-summary) a read.

Comment: As soon as `Is >= 1` evaluates to true, the other test on that line is not evaluated that's the category you get

Comment: According to [link](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/case.php)[link], "Conditions that are evaluated in the order listed. Once a condition is found to be true, it will execute the corresponding code and not evaluate the conditions any further.", so as Tim said, once `Is >= 1`, it stops.

Comment: @All Thank you. I changed the variable to be `Long` instead of `Integer` and as @Tim Williams said, my syntaxis was wrong; what I meant was: `Case 1 To 30`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `Case` evaluation ends as soon as the first test passes.

For example:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim a As Long

    a = 20

    Select Case a
        Case Is <= 0: Debug.Print "zero or less"
        Case Is >= v1, Is <= v15: Debug.Print "1-15"
        Case Is >= 16, Is <= 30: Debug.Print "16-30"
    End Select
End Sub

Function v1()
    Debug.Print "Called v1"
    v1 = 1
End Function

Function v15()
    Debug.Print "Called v15"
    v15 = 15
End Function
```

Output:

```
Called v1
1-15
```

So v15 is never called because that test is skipped.

Comment: My syntaxis was wrong. What I meant was `Case 1 To 30` as @Tim Williams commented above, in the question. So that's why I always got "Category B", because it always was evaluated to 1. Thanks again!